# Free Alternative to Ubigraph

Tags: python, graph, visualization

I am trying to generate a large graph visualization using [Ubigraph](http://ubietylab.net/ubigraph/content/Docs/index.html) and its xml-rpc interface. However Ubigraph's xmlRPC server is not fast enough to handle the call rate generated by my python code, and freezes. I have tried all the performance tips listed on the website to no avail. The direct wrapper is not available in the free version of Ubigraph, hence my question: are there any Free (as in speech) alternatives to Ubigraph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you may be having the same problem I was.  It is not that ubigraph cannot handle the xmlrpc, but that there is a problem with the 64-bit release.  It kept freezing on me at completely unpredictable times (sometimes after 22 edges, sometimes after 1500 edges...).
Try the 32-bit release instead.  It has been solid for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org)? Does this *have* to be a service, or could you just run it locally?

Comment: This to run locally. to provide performant interactive graph visualization.Graphviz won't do for this task